# how to install python module on dataproc cluster executors

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, xmltodict

how can we import xmltodict module to all worker nodes of cluster, now it's giving me error as ' no name module ' while performing xmltodict on pyspark dataframe

xmltodict python module should be install on all executors of dataproc cluster